# React Router Dom v6 render not redirecting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

```js
          <Route
            exact
            path="/register"
            element={<Register />}
            render={() => !isAuthenticated ? <Register/> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />}
          />
```

Okay so i want to redirect to login if user is not authenticated and "isAuthenticated" is normally set to false but it wont redirect me. Not a single error is logged. I replaced `<Navigate />` with `console.log("something")` to see if there is something wrong with component imported from `React-Router-Dom` but that "something" is not logging. I tried all still don't know what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: If you try to put isAuthenticated outside render and have two separate <Route> components depends on condition? Does it change something?

Comment: nope it doesn't

Comment: Confused?? you set `isAuthenticated = false;` then, it will evaluate to true since `!isAuthenticated` will equal true and therefore, render `<Register/>`. It will only redirect to login if `isAuthenticated = true;`

Answer (score 1):

1. Logic error?

`isAuthenticated = false` by default.
You want:

- false > 'Login'
- true > `<Register/>`

But you put `!isAuthenticated` so it's the inverse:

- false > `<Register/>`
- true > 'Login'

2. Change the ternary into something more easily comprehensive.

Why not: `isAuthenticated ? <Navigate replace to="/login" /> : <Register/>`. 
Save me the headache.

3. Navigate properties

Be explicit with the properties

```js
<Navigate replace to="/login" />
/*or replace={false} */ <Navigate replace={true} to="/login" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `react-router-dom` v5 and v6 syntaxes. The RRDv6 `Route` components no longer take a `render` function prop (*nor a `component` prop or `children` function prop*) and now take only a single `element` prop taking JSX to render the routed content.

Remove the `render` prop and move the conditional logic into the `element` prop.

```
<Route
  path="/register"
  element={!isAuthenticated ? <Register /> : <Navigate replace to="/login" />}
/>
```

If this is a pattern you use often then abstract it into an `AuthLayout` component that conditionally renders an `Outlet` for nested routes you want to protect or the `Navigate` component to redirect.

```
const AuthLayout = ({ isAuthenticated }) => 
  !isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
```

...

```
<Route element={<AuthLayout isAuthenticated={isAuthenticated} />}>
  <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
</Route>
```

***Note:** I think you've possibly mixed up what you want to render when `isAuthenticated` is true as generally you'd want to redirect to the authentication route when not authenticated.*

In other words, if authenticated, render the routed component in the outlet, otherwise redirect to login route.

```
const AuthLayout = ({ isAuthenticated }) => 
  isAuthenticated
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate replace to="/login" />;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should lose "exact" from the routes, as it was changed in v6 version.

https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5

as per react router

> `<Route exact>` is gone. Instead, routes with descendant routes (defined in other components) use a trailing * in their path to indicate they match deeply